# Share model object in java mvc

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm making an application by MVC architecture. My question is: how can I share an istance of a model between many classes in controller?

It is difficult 'cause I'm using a listener,I would call by this listener a controller passing it a model:

```
class ButtonListener1 implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());


        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Inizia")){

            //call a controller passing it a model
        } 

    }


}
```

Comment: Pass the same model object reference in each controller's constructor.

Comment: In `request.getServletContext()` but you need take care for their synchronization.

Comment: I'm not developing a website, i'm not using a servlet

Comment: You can use `Singleton` pattern if you need only one instance for all.

Comment: Have I use singleton directly in model implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct a button, you can set the model.